# Hanami rake task does not load repositories

Tags: ruby, hanami

I have hanami 1.3.0 app named `booking`. There is rake task in `/rakelib/motel.rake` :

```
require_relative '../lib/booking' # it requires booking/motel/booker file

namespace :motel do
  task :book do
    Booking::Motel::Booker.new.book
  end
end
```

`booking/motel/booker` requires booking_repository file, and tries to instantiate BookingRepository, but fails with error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Hanami::Repository
<root>/lib/booking/repositories/booking_repository.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
```

However, when I run `Booking::Motel::Booker.new.book` in hanami console, it loads `BookingRepository` without problems.

Looked at numerous stack questions regarding hanami rake, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it was a foolish mistake. I forgot to add `:environment` to my task.

```
namespace :motel do
  task book: :environment do
    Booking::Motel::Booker.new.book
  end
end
```

That fixed it and dropped the need to use manual file loading, of course.